# partitioning boolean lattice into the smallest number of chains

Tags: lattice

As a result of the Dilowrth's theorm we know that the Boolean Lattic can be partitioned into    $\dbinom{n}{n/2}$ chains and it is the smallest number of such chains. Another question regarding that, is who many different possible partitioning of a boolean lattic into smallest chains does exists?
I have some ideas. For example to start from one possible partitioning and find out other possible ones. Please help me with more ideas.

Comment: Dilworth's theorem says that the size of the largest antichain is equal to the size of the smallest chain partition in *any* poset. The fact you state is a consequence of Dilworth's theorem, and Sperner's lemma.

Comment: Like! (not sure that's the term used on the forum, but you know what I mean)